# Is a SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY faster in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having trouble finding how quickly queries run because of how snowflake caches results, but which of these two queries is the 'right' way to do it? (or is there an even better way?):

```
select left.*, right.name from LEFT_TABLE left inner join (
  select distinct ID, NAME from RIGHT_TABLE
) right on left.id = right.id;
```

or:

```
select left.*, right.name from LEFT_TABLE left inner join (
  select any_value(ID) as ID, any_value(NAME) as NAME
  from RIGHT_TABLE
  group by ID
) right on left.id = right.id;
```

LEFT_TABLE looks something like this:

| A | B | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13.18 | 677.92 | 112 |
| 15.65 | 971.36 | 113 |
| 2.72 | 991.00 | 114 |
| 33.54 | 755.18 | 116 |
| 5.14 | 588.12 | 115 |

And RIGHT_TABLE looks something like this:

| PK | ID | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 251 | 112 | John Doe |
| 287 | 112 | John Doe |
| 232 | 112 | Jane Bow |
| 242 | 113 | Jane Bow |
| 234 | 113 | Jane Bow |

Comment: they should be the same , but you can look at their execution plan to find out more about behind the scen of each query

Comment: The two queries do different things.   You should use the version that does what you want.  Unless of course you *know* that name is always unique for an `id`.

Comment: In RIGHT_TABLE the same `ID` always corresponds to the same `NAME`

Comment: Since that's the case, using ANY_VALUE() will be faster for single queries but be careful of its effect on result set caching. ANY_VALUE() is a non deterministic function, so if something like a BI dashboard runs the query periodically between data changes on the tables, Snowflake will not be able to use the result set cache and have to run the query again.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 different caches involved in processing a query in Snowflake:

1. result set cache:

- This is the "all or nothing" result; you either get the final answer directly without any processing, or you get nothing; no "partial benefit" here.
- This is in the global services layer of our architecture, and is NOT specific to any single virtual warehouse (compute) used to process the query.
- Results are retained for 24 hours, but you have the ability to tell the query processor to NOT pull from this cache.

2. metadata cache:

- Also in the global services layer
- Stores statistical information on micro-partitions; used to build query query execution plan
- Will eventually be "swapped out" by other queries over time; you have NO CONTROL over this cache

3. data cache

- This is a "traditional" data cache, at the micro-partition-level.
- This IS specific to the virtual warehouse (compute) used to process the query. As a result, if the virtual warehouse is suspended, the cache is (typically) lost. That said, you should be aware that suspending and immediately resuming might result in the warehouse never actually suspending (as an optimization) and therefore not flushing the cache.

Bottom line: if you plan to do performance comparisons between multiple runs of a query, you should probably (1) disable result set caching on the session and (2) suspend, then wait (maybe a minute), and then resume the virtual warehouse between query executions. Then confirm (in the SQL Query history window) that there was no data caching used for the query (color-coded in the "Bytes Scanned" column... blue=local=cached, green=remote=uncached).

Source: snowflake community forum

Answer (score 0):

You can disable both the data and result set cache and then time your queries.

to disable the result set cache:

```
ALTER SESSION SET USE_CACHED_RESULT = FALSE;
```

to clear the data cache:

```
ALTER WAREHOUSE WH_NAME SUSPEND;
ALTER WAREHOUSE WH_NAME RESUME;
```